# Couchapp default template missing on windows?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I installed CouchDB and Couchapp  on Win7 machine and when I try to run couchapp generate app contacts I get:

```
2014-11-21 22:01:00 [ERROR] couchapp error: Can't create a CouchApp in C:\Users\ Antonio\Desktop\contacts: default template not found.
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a path like this:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\couchapp\templates\app_attachments

The contents of this directory are the template.
The simplest template is a html document.
You can build up a structure of directories of linked documents (css, script etc)

Specifically my directory is like this

> \index.html
>   \style\main.css
>   \script\app.js